# Unload oci.dll from Biztalk execution

Tags: windows, oracle, dll, biztalk, oracle-call-interface

When running Biztalk application, it loads the oci.dll (Oracle Call Interface).

We don't need the oracle to be loaded along with BTSNTSvc.exe.

We removed all Orchestrations and Adapters related to Oracle. But still it's showing up.

What's the procedure to exclude the oci.dll from loading on execution of BTSNTSvc.exe.

[image: Biztalk Having Oci]

Answer (score 0):

Have you checked whether you still have any Oracle Handlers defined in the BizTalk Management Console?

After that, I would check the appropriate BTSNTSvc.exe.config for any assemblyBinding elements under /configuration/runtime that is explicitly, or possibly implicitly, loading that assembly.